# Не могу разобраться с кодировками.

Tags: ajax, кодировка, php

Вообщем проблема в том, что у меня когда данные из БД грузятся по аяксу они выводятся краказяблями, если запрашиваю файл на прямую, то ответ получаю в нормальной виде, а когда по аяксу то пфф..
Вот код всех файлов которые используются. 
При подключении к базе указываю кодировку в которой должны придти данные.

```
$charset = "cp1251";
mysql_set_charset($charset, $dblink);
```

В скрипте указываю тоже кодировку

```
$.ajax({
                url: file+".php",  
                cache: false,
                scriptCharset: "cp1251",
                success: function(data){  
                    $(".body").html(data);
```

Все данные в базе записаны тоже в кодировке `cp1251` все скрипты и пхпшники тоже в кодировке `cp1251`. Что делать, я сейчас чуть-ли не повешусь.

Comment: Поиском иногда тоже надо пользоваться, вчера вечером подобная проблема была решена http://hashcode.ru/questions/67781/проблема-с-кодировкой-куска-сайта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В аякс запросе стоит послать сформированный заголовок:

либо этот:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=cp1251');
```

либо этот:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=cp1251');
```

Попробуйте указать этот заголовок явно через php.Поможет.Тут с ним нужно поиграться.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)))))

Comment: На здоровье )